# get inputs from OS application even if app is not active (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, x11

Having some app, made with x11 libs, tested for ubuntu.
It takes simple keyboard inputs and outputs corresponding value.
It works fine if application window (ubuntu terminal) is currently open

linux-kbhit.h

```
#define     ESC     "\033"
#define     UP      "\033[A"
#define     DOWN    "\033[B"
#define     LEFT    "\033[D"
#define     RIGHT   "\033[C"
#define     A   "a"

void term_setup(void (*sighandler)(int));
void term_restore();
bool kbhit();
bool keydown(const char* key);
```

linux-kbhit.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

static struct termios oldtio;
static struct termios curtio;

void term_setup(void (*sighandler)(int)){
    struct sigaction sa;

    /* Save stdin terminal attributes */
    tcgetattr(0, &oldtio);

    if(sighandler){
    /* Make sure we exit cleanly */
        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
        sa.sa_handler = sighandler;
        sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    }

    /* This is needed to be able to tcsetattr() after a hangup (Ctrl-C)
     * see tcsetattr() on POSIX
     */
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGTTOU, &sa, NULL);

    /* Set non-canonical no-echo for stdin */
    tcgetattr(0, &curtio);
    curtio.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &curtio);
}

void term_restore(){
    /* restore terminal attributes */
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
}

static char get[4]= {0};
bool kbhit(){
    struct pollfd pfds[1];
    int ret;
    memset(get, 0, sizeof(char) * 4);

    /* See if there is data available */
    pfds[0].fd = 0;
    pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
    ret = poll(pfds, 1, 0);

    /* Consume data */
    if (ret > 0) {
        read(0, get, 3);
        return strlen(get) > 0;
    }
    return false;
}

bool keydown(const char* key){
    return !strcmp(get, key);
}
```

it works perfect for keyboard inputs for active application, but application purpose is to get all OS key inputs and interpret it for further use

main.c

```
#include "linux-kbhit.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <signal.h>

static sig_atomic_t end = 0;
static void sighandler(int signo)
{
    end = 1;
    printf("good beye!\n");
}

int main()
{
    term_setup(sighandler);

    while (!end) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            if (keydown(ESC))
                printf("This is \"ESC\" button!\n");
            if (keydown(UP))
                printf("This is \"UP\" button!\n");
            if (keydown(DOWN))
                printf("This is \"DOWN\" button!\n");
            if (keydown(LEFT))
                printf("This is \"LEFT\" button!\n");
            if (keydown(RIGHT))
                printf("This is \"RIGHT\" button!\n");
            if (keydown(A))
                printf("This is \"A\" button!\n");
        }
    }

    term_restore();

    return 0;
}
```

I need to get keys from any app within OS (Ubuntu)
How can should I amend the code?

Comment: Consider https://askubuntu.com/questions/87311/how-to-intercept-all-keystrokes

Comment: You are receiving input from stdin which is PTY provided by terminal emulator. Terminal emulator receives it's input from Xorg. How are you going to receive keys if inactive terminal window doesn't receive them? You should grab X11 input, not stdin.

Comment: So you want your app run like an macro recorder or PRNT SCRN key?

Comment: Maybe look into existing applications, e.g. [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd)

Comment: Maybe this is something you're looking for: [libevdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev), [wikipedia - evdev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev)

Answer (score 0):

I need to make analog of QuickTextPaste for Ubuntu
You can make settings:
if press control + T you get pop up menu, each bullet sends paste of needed command and you can use it
https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/QuickTextPaste/Screenshot-2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your application is built using XWindow libraries, you will not be able to control all inputs when you start XWindow connection to the server, as the XWindow keyboard events don't enter the application through the normal tty input.  If the application has the keyboard focus, it doesn't matter what key you press (ctrl-d, ctrl-c or ctrl-]) to generate EOF, SIGINT or SIGQUIT.  As those keys are encoded through the keyboard event manager (through the server tcp/unix socket) and never through the standard input file descriptor.

BTW, you have some misconceptions in your treatment of the tty `termios` driver.  You say

> This is needed to be able to tcsetattr() after a hangup (Ctrl-C)

a hangup is what happens when the modem deasserts the DSR modem line and results in a `SIGHUP` signal (it is generated by the tty driver when the user signals a terminal end of file, and is sent to all processes in the process group controlling the terminal) but you have set the terminal settings to raw mode, and then, no control character processing is made in the tty driver, so the caracters are passed to the process without handling/generating `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP` or `SIGQUIT`  (this last, generated normally by Ctrl-], and producing a core dump of the process, if enabled)  This (the hangup) is generated by Ctrl-D, and not by Ctrl-C (which normally generates `SIGINT`, instead)  But as I say, if you move to raw mode, no character processing is done in the tty driver and you get the characters *raw*.

- Ctrl-C produces `ASCII ETX` (end of text) character without interrupting the program with `SIGINT`.
- Ctrl-D produces `ASCII EOT` (end of transmission) character without signalling no more data to the tty driver.  As of this, no `SIGHUP` will be delivered to the process group.
- Ctrl-] produces `ASCII GS` (group separator) character without signalling `SIGQUIT` to the process (and no core dump)